# Create trigger with after insert random string

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table `app` and columns `ID, PW` and `ID auto increment`. I want to create trigger, when I insert new row(`ID`), then insert `PW` column random string, example 75Da5A(length 7), please help

```
ID   PW
1    75Da5A
2    45daa8
3    571as5
----------
---------
```

Comment: How far have you got? Are you stuck on the trigger syntax, or generating a random string, or both? (And are you really storing passwords in plain text?)

Comment: yes I now.................

Comment: Alex Poole trigger syntax I have a query who generate random code, but I need trigger
**select UPPER(SUBSTR(TRANSLATE(dbms_random.string('p',100) ,'A`~!@#$%^&*()- =_+[]\{}|;'':",./<>?' ,'A'),1,7))FROM dual**

Comment: So please post what you tried so far to better explain the issue you are having. Is the problem in creating a random string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need something like the following:

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE app ( id NUMBER GENERATED BY DEFAULT ON NULL AS IDENTITY,
  2                     pwd varchar2(16));

Table created.

SQL> create or replace trigger randomPwd
  2  before insert on app
  3  for each row
  4  begin
  5      if :new.pwd is null then
  6          :new.pwd := dbms_random.string('a', 7);
  7      end if;
  8  end;
  9  /

Trigger created.

SQL> insert into app values ('', '');

1 row created.

SQL> select * from app;

        ID PWD
---------- ----------------
         1 RVaQalX
```

You can use  [`dbms_random.string`](http://docs.oracle.com/database/122/ARPLS/DBMS_RANDOM.htm#GUID-6217A957-6E09-4BAB-B0D0-EB9DC0FCAECA) to get random strings in different ways, with no need to edit the result.

From [Oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/database/122/ARPLS/DBMS_RANDOM.htm#GUID-6217A957-6E09-4BAB-B0D0-EB9DC0FCAECA):

> - 'u', 'U' - returning string in uppercase alpha characters
> - 'l', 'L' - returning string in lowercase alpha characters
> - 'a', 'A' - returning string in mixed case alpha characters
> - 'x', 'X' - returning string in uppercase alpha-numeric characters
> - 'p', 'P' - returning string in any printable characters.